# How can i check if a specific sub directory already exist?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp

The code i'm using now:

```
string[] Files = GetFileList();
ArrayList arrDirectories = new ArrayList();
if (Files != null)
{
  foreach (string dir in Files)
  {
    arrDirectories.Add(dir);
  }
}
if (!arrDirectories.Contains(dirName))
{
  Sync(dirName, reqFTP, response, ftpStream);
}
```

The method GetFileList:

```
public string[] GetFileList()
{
  string[] downloadFiles;
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  WebResponse response = null;
  StreamReader reader = null;
  try
  {
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + f.Host + "/"));
    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(f.Username, f.Password);
    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    reqFTP.Proxy = null;
    reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
    reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
    response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
    reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
      result.Append(line);
      result.Append("\n");
      line = reader.ReadLine();
    }
    result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
    return result.ToString().Split('\n');
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     if (reader != null)
     {
       reader.Close();
     }
     if (response != null)
     {
       response.Close();
     }
     downloadFiles = null;
     return downloadFiles;
    }
 }
```

What i'm getting in the end in arrDirectories is all the files and directories and sub directories from my ftp server. The problem is that each file,directory,and sub directory are in it's own index.
For example i see in index 0 in arrDirectories: test
Then in index 1 i see: testsub
Then in index 2 i see: test.jpg

But in fact test is under root directory and testsub is under test and test.jpg is under testsub.
The problem is that when i check if directory already exist:

```
if (!arrDirectories.Contains(dirName))
```

If it's a single directory for example test then there is no problem.
But if the directory i want to check if exist is a sub directory like test/testsub
Then it will never find it even if it is exist on my ftp server.

So in case i have to check a directories like test/testsub or test/test1/test2/test3...what should i change first in the GEtFileList method ? And then how to loop over the arrDirectories maybe need a recursive ?

Comment: Don't build a string, only to Split() it later. Instead add the lines you get to an result-list

Answer (score 0):

try using this code'
first get the directory structure into string array:

```js
string[] Directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\windows\Temp", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

then use linq to checkout if your directory exsists

```js
bool DirectoryExists = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Directories.Where(d => d.ToLower().Contains(@"Directory Name...")).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right, the simplest way - call GetFileList() recursively
And put results into list, not into string
Here is your modified code

```
    static public void GetFileList(List<string> list,string sroot)
    {

        WebResponse response = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + Host+sroot));
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails ;
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            string file;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream ) 
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    file = sroot + "/" + line.Substring(57);
                    list.Add(file);
                }
                else if (line.StartsWith("d"))
                {
                    file = sroot + "/" + line.Substring(57);
                    list.Add(file+"/");
                    GetFileList(list, file);
                }
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

- Calls method ListDirectoryDetails instead of ListDirectory to
  distinguish directories and files
- Parses result to get file name from file details (am not sure it is always the end of line starting from pos. 57 :-)
- Calls self for each found folder
- The criteria of the end of stream is EndOfStream :-)

Here is the call

```
List<string> filelist = new List<string>();
GetFileList(filelist, "");
foreach (string s in filelist )
    Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(1));
```

All folders have "/" at the end (feel free to do not include folders into list). 
It's easy to build local file list using method from previous answer.